# Error using google-api-python-client

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm following the instructions on how to [upload files to Google Drive using Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) having successfully authenticated (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)).

I load the necessary libraries with...

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
```

..and yet on attempting to run an upload of my own I'm informed...

```
NameError: name 'MediaFileUpload' is not defined
```

Any pointers or suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: guess you need to import *MediaFileUpload*

Answer (score 0):

Below is the entire script on how to Upload/Download in Drive API using both Python 2 and Python 3 from [Wesley Chun's blogpost](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

FILES = (
    ('hello.txt', False),
    ('hello.txt', True),
)

for filename, convert in FILES:
    metadata = {'title': filename}
    res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
            media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()
    if res:
        print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename, res['mimeType']))

if res:
    MIMETYPE = 'application/pdf'
    res, data = DRIVE._http.request(res['exportLinks'][MIMETYPE])
    if data:
        fn = '%s.pdf' % os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        with open(fn, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(data)
        print('Downloaded "%s" (%s)' % (fn, MIMETYPE))
```